# Are there multiple active spells in Smite?

Tags: smite

I just started playing Smite, so I may not be using the correct terminolgy.  During the games, I used the <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>G</kbd> "spells" quite often.  The <kbd>F</kbd> spell restored mana, and the <kbd>G</kbd> spell gives a speed boost.

I compare these to the summoner spells in League of Legends where you have a handful to choose from before the game.  Does Smite have spells to chose from as well, or is it currently just the mana restore and speed boost spells?

I looked on the smite wiki, and all I found was the [Controls page](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Controls), where it labels the <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>G</kbd> keys as Store Active 1 and Store Active 2 respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, one doesn't get to choose spells. Each character has a predetermined list of actions/spells/abilities.

Each character has 5 unique abilities that are broken down into:

- 1 passive ability
- 3 "spells"
- 1 ultimate ability

The reason why I quote "spells" is that not all characters are magic users.

If you have auto level and auto items on (which it is by default) it will automatically level up your spells in the order HiRez (the game developer) has defined. You can override this order by unchecking autoleveling (which means you'll have to manually upgrade each level in game) or if you click on the "gods" menu *you* can define the auto leveling order.

The 2 abilities you were referring to are known as "actives". Think of an active as an item you can purchase that grants you a special ability. This special ability is on a cooldown timer. You have unlimited uses and once you buy an item you cannot sell it or discard. You only have 2 slots for active items.

You can view all items/armor/weapons/etc currently in game here: https://account.hirezstudios.com/smitegame/items.aspx I recommend sorting it by grid as opposed to list. (blue button, top right)

Please note that the game is still in beta and they do add/modify/remove items frequently between patches so make sure you read the patch notes after each patch.

Some of the items that are considered "actives" are:

- Aegis Amulet
- Blink
- Creeping Curse
- Girdle of Might
- Hand of the gods
- Heavenly Agility
- Meditation
- Purification Beads
- Shielded Recall
- Sprint

I also have a small tutorial page at http://www.teamlqd.com/1/post/2013/11/smite-once-you-smite-you-know-its-right.html

Comment: Yep because the actives has been changed alot, first they were expensive 700g, then they made em cheap 250g and now they made them with 3 tiers like items raising the cost but adding some extra rewards like meditation healing you aswell ect...

Comment: Thanks so much - I found the "actives" category in the shop - that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You are playing with auto buy on I presume. The autobuy system starts you off with sprint and meditation. Smite is a little different than LoL. You get 'spells' once you are in the game. When you enter the shop (default key 'I') you can see all the items in the game. The area that would most apply to this quiestion would be the 'actives' tab. There is quite a large amount of actives to choose from. Slowing down enemies, speeding up allies, quick damage to AI creeps, CC immunity, and even complete invulnerability are some of the items to choose from.

[Smite Active items](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Category:Ability_items)

You would have to turn off autobuy in the god selection screen to prevent it from getting sprint and meditation for your first buys...

Just remember, once you buy an active, it cannot be sold. Choose them wisely.

Comment: Yes, I was using auto-buy :)  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The spells, usage bound to F and G by default, are called “active”. There are multiple actives to choose from in the item shop.

With auto-buy enabled, you will always get the meditation and sprint actives you referred to. To change this you have two options:

- Keep auto-buy enabled and change the actives on a per-god level in the main menu in the guide section.
- Disable auto-buy and buy actives yourself.

Also note that auto-buy generally only buys level one of the active items, where as by now all active items have three levels, increasing their effectiveness and providing alternative characteristics.

For a reference of the available active items see [smitewiki for example](http://smite.gamepedia.com/List_of_active_items) or in-game in the item store dialog.